# Can you use Stylus, Jade, and Coffeescript for development with a native mobile wrapper like Trigger.io?

Tags: html, css, coffeescript, trigger.io, forge

I'm excited to be starting on my first project, and just wondering if you have any experience or pointers about the best way to use Stylus, Jade, and Coffeescript for development?

I'm sure I can figure something out, but thought I'd see if there was a recommended/fastest way.

Comment: Too general of a question.. please try this at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ . Thank You So Much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. A Trigger.io user modified the basic template app using those technologies and you can see the [code on Github](https://github.com/mhuebert/Forge-Bootstrap).

More generally you can add customized steps to the Trigger.io build process, such as doing coffeescript compiles, using hooks. The documentation for that is here: http://docs.trigger.io/en/latest/tools/hooks.html

Comment: Thanks! the documentation is helpful.